# Remove duplicates nested list Python dependend on position

Tags: python, list, nested, duplicates

in a nested list like the one below, I'd like to remove duplicates depending on the position.

```
[[1,2,3,4], [2,1,3,4], [1,2,3,4], [1,3,2,4]]
```

So every sub-list contains the same numbers, but in different order. If the order of the numbers is the same, I would like to delete this duplicate. So the list above should look like:

```
[[1,2,3,4], [2,1,3,4], [1,3,2,4]]
```

I have tried to write some code by myself, but since I am a beginner, there is no working result. I have tried:

```
result = []
for i in test_list:
    if i not in result:
        result.append(i)
return result
```

Or

```
tpls = [tuple(x) for x in test_list]
dct = list(dict.fromkeys(tpls))
dup_free = [list(x) for x in test_list]
return dup_free
```

Thanks!

EDIT2: Sorry everbody, the input was wrong so the code just could not work...

Comment: In your second solution, you wrote `test_list` instead of `dct`.

Comment: Why `return` statement is here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
lst = [[1,2,3,4], [2,1,3,4], [1,2,3,4], [1,3,2,4]]

new_lst = []
for a in lst:
    if a not in new_lst: # check if current element already in the new_lst or not.
        new_lst.append(a)
print(new_lst)
```

OUTPUT

```py
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 1, 3, 4], [1, 3, 2, 4]]
```

Comment: I also have tried this code, however it does not seem to work

Comment: @Ic3Cub3 But it's working.

Comment: @Ic3Cub3 Can you copy this code and run on your computer?

Comment: I copied the code, ran it on my computer with the full list, but it only returns [[3, 4, 1, 2]]

Comment: @Ic3Cub3 Can you show the full list.

Comment: I added the full list in the main question above

Comment: @Ic3Cub3 What output do you expect.

Comment: @Ic3Cub3 It's print `[[3,4,1,2]]` Because all the list inside list are same.

Comment: @Ic3Cub3 is your expected output is this `[3,4,1,2]`

Comment: yeah sorry my input list was just wrong. My bad...

Comment: @Ic3Cub3 Okk. Next time take a look before uploading a question

Answer (score 1):

You can use pandas for this purpose.

```
import pandas as pd

aaa = {'date': ['2022-05-02', '2022-04-29', ' 2022-04-29', '2022-04-28 ', '2022-04-28 ', '2022-04-28 '],
       'id': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C'], 'number': [397177, 53876, 191214, 75824, 483860, 51731]}

df = pd.DataFrame(aaa)
df = df.drop_duplicates().values
```

Output

```
[[1 2 3 4]
 [2 1 3 4]
 [1 3 2 4]]
```

Answer (score 1):

First one is working run this code :

```
X = [[1,2,3,4], [2,1,3,4], [1,2,3,4], [1,3,2,4]]

def Rem_Dup(L) :
    result = []
    for i in L:
        if i not in result:
            result.append(i)
    return result

print(Rem_Dup(X))
```

Answer (score 1):

For each sublist `sublst` in the original nested list, convert into tuple for lookup in the dictionary `dct`. Add to the resulting list without dups `nodups` only if we have not seen it:

```
lst = [[1,2,3,4], [2,1,3,4], [1,2,3,4], [1,3,2,4]]
nodups = []
dct = {}

for sublst in lst:
    tup = tuple(sublst)
    if tup not in dct:
        dct[tup] = 1
        nodups.append(sublst)
    else:
        pass
print(nodups)
# [[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 1, 3, 4], [1, 3, 2, 4]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in one line with a list comprehension:

```
a = [[1,2,3,4], [2,1,3,4], [1,2,3,4], [1,3,2,4]]
[j for i, j in enumerate(a) if j not in a[i+1:]]
```

Output:

```
[[2, 1, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 3, 2, 4]]
```

Note: This will choose the last occurrence of that sublist in the original list if you care about the ordering

Edit: If you care about ordering, you can go through the list backwards and then reverse the result:

```
[j for i, j in enumerate(reversed(a)) if j not in list(reversed(a))[i+1:]][::-1]
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 1, 3, 4], [1, 3, 2, 4]]
```